# reference to 'list' is ambiguous including header file

Tags: c++, header-files

When I add  'bits/stdc++.h'header file, it shows   [Error] reference to 'list' is ambiguous. But when I erase the header and remain all other headers, the code is compiling properly.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sstream>
#define LIST_INIT_SIZE 2
#define NULL_VALUE -99999
#define SUCCESS_VALUE 99999
using namespace std;
int listMaxSize;
int * list;
int length;


void initializeList()
{
    listMaxSize = LIST_INIT_SIZE;
    list = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*listMaxSize) ;
    length = 0 ;
}
```

Comment: "When I add 'bits/stdc++.h' header file" -- that's the problem. You should not add or use the `bits/stdc++.h` header file. Whichever book taught you to do that, you should throw it away and get a proper C++ book. Whichever web site you read this from, you should lose the bookmark. That's not standard C++.

Comment: also take a look at: [why is "using namespace std" considered bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thats because  the header `<bits/stdc++.h>` has its own version of list i.e. from the list template `<list>`.
Having two copies or different definitions of the same would result in ambiguity.
If its working without the bits header (STL) then simply dont use it.